# Can't find <div ng-view> from NBA stats website with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to Scrape this NBA website `https://stats.nba.com/team/1610612738/`. What I'm trying to do is to extract player's name, NO, POS and all the information for every player. The problem is that I can't find or my code can't find `<div ng-view>` that's the parent of `<nba-stat-table >` where the table is.

My code so far is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_Player():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'D:\Documents\Python\Web Scraping\phantomjs.exe')

    url = 'https://stats.nba.com/team/1610612738/'

    driver.get(url)

    data = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

    div1 = soup.find('div', class_="columns / small-12 / section-view-overlay")
    print(div1.find_all('div'))

get_Player()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the json response endpoint which the page uses to get that content. Far easier and nicer to handle and no need for selenium. You can find it in the network tab.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://stats.nba.com/stats/commonteamroster?LeagueID=00&Season=2018-19&TeamID=1610612738',  headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}).json()
players_info = r['resultSets'][0]
df = pd.DataFrame(players_info['rowSet'], columns = players_info['headers'])
print(df.head())
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, how do you convert : "https://stats.nba.com/team/1610612738/" into "https://stats.nba.com/stats/commonteamroster?LeagueID=00&Season=2018-19&TeamID=1610612738". I got the same issue with the URL: "http://www.yuantaetfs.com/en/#/Orders/2005". Many thanks

Comment: Hiya. Please consider opening a new question explaining what you have tried and where you are stuck. I am not on here much at present so you are more likely to get a quick answer that way.

Answer (score 1):

`find_all` function always return a list, `findChildren()` is return all child of tag object, [more details](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/beautifulsoup_ref.html)

Replace your code:

```
div1 = soup.find('div', class_="columns / small-12 / section-view-overlay")
print(div1.find_all('div'))
```

To:

```
div = soup.find('div', {'class':"nba-stat-table__overflow"})
for tr in div.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    for td in tr.findChildren():
        print(td.text)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_Player():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'D:\Documents\Python\Web Scraping\phantomjs.exe')

    url = 'https://stats.nba.com/team/1610612738/'

    driver.get(url)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "nba-stat-table__overflow")))

    data = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

    div = soup.find('div', {'class':"nba-stat-table__overflow"})
    for tr in div.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
        for td in tr.findChildren():
            print(td.text)

get_Player()
```

O/P:

```
Jayson Tatum
Jayson Tatum
#0
F
6-8
208 lbs
MAR 03, 1998
21
1
Duke
Jonathan Gibson
Jonathan Gibson
#3
G
6-2
185 lbs
NOV 08, 1987
31
2
New Mexico State
....
```

Comment: Isn't working. I got an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`. When I print only  `div` the output is `None`.

Comment: The code worked amazing, I also tried using Chrome instead of PhantomJS and it also worked great

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to find all the `div's` , If it's just the **Player** **name** that you want to extract, you can use this `css selector` :

```
td.player a
```

**Code** :

```
all_player = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.player a')
for playername in all_player:
   print(playername.text)
```

Comment: The last two lines inside the function show that when you print all the div's, there isn't a <div ng-view> 
and consequently I can't see the childrens of that div. I tried using your code and I didn't work. Thank you